# Problem of generalization of a model determining image similarity (Siamese Neural Network)

Tags: image, deep-learning, pytorch, cosine-similarity, siamese-network

I've trained a Siamese Neural Network to predict image similarity with 5 classes (1=not equal, ..., 5=exactly the same).
The similarity is measured by Cosine Similarity which results in values from -1 to 1. To train the model I've therefore transformed my original scale to these values, e.g. the "not equal" class 1 to -1, class 2 to -0.5, ... and "exactly the same" class 5 to 1.
Regarding the [results of the prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpRYi.png) one can see that the predictions of the model has an ascending median with ascending similarity (from 1 to 5). But the scale (-1 to 1) is not fully used as the results are too close to each other. On the other hand the separation of the training data is very good, so I think that the problem can be solved, but right now the generalization on new image pairs which the model hasn't seen before does not yet work quite well.
I think this is a result of overfitting, but I don't know what else I can do to solve this problem.
That's why I ask you if someone has an idea what I could do to improve the separation of the classes.
Here are the configurations of my training model:

- The training set is balanced (~500 Image Pairs / Class)
- The CNN for the Siamese Neural Network is a trained ResNet34 to the specific images
- Distance Function: Cosine Similarity
- Optimizer: RMSPROP(lr=0.00001)
- Epochs: 500
- Batch Size: 32
- Loss-Function: SmoothL1Loss
- Avoid Overfitting: resize(105,105), randomRotation([-30,30]), ColorJitter(brightness=[0.7,1])
- Architecture: cutted last layer from ResNet34 and adding a Linear Layer (see below)

```
def cutting_model(model):
    head = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[0])
   
    #Select last Layer
    body = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[1][:-1])
    model2 = nn.Sequential(head, body)
    
    return model2
    
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
                     
        self.cnn1 = cutting_model(model)#, False, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512,100))
    
    def forward_once(self, x):
        
        # Forward pass 
        output = self.cnn1(x)
        output = output.view(output.size()[0], -1)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        return output

    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        
        output1 = self.forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(input2)
        return output1, output2
```

- Train Method:

```
def train():
    cos = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1, eps=1e-6)
    
    for epoch in range(0,Config.train_number_epochs):

        for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader,0):
            img0, img1 , label = data
            img0, img1 , label = img0.cuda(), img1.cuda() , label.cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output1, output2 = net(img0,img1)
            cosine_distance = cos(output1, output2)
            label=label.squeeze()
            loss_function = criterion(cosine_distance, label)
            loss_function.backward()
            optimizer.step()
                
    return net
```

My current Siamese Neural Network:

```
SiameseNetwork(
  (cnn1): Sequential(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (4): Sequential(
        (0): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (1): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (2): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (5): Sequential(
        (0): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (2): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (3): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (6): Sequential(
        (0): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (2): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (3): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (4): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (5): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (7): Sequential(
        (0): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
        (2): BasicBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): AdaptiveConcatPool2d(
        (ap): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
        (mp): AdaptiveMaxPool2d(output_size=1)
      )
      (1): Flatten()
      (2): BatchNorm1d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
      (4): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (6): BatchNorm1d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (7): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    )
  )
  (fc1): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=100, bias=True)
  )
)
```

I've tried:

- different Optimizers (Adam, Eve)
- different LearningRates (0.00025,0.0001,0.000075,0.000005, 0.0000025, 0.000001)
- instead of CosineSimilarity (range -1:1) I've tried Cosine Distance (range 0:2)
- different Epochs (200-3000)
- different Batch-sizes (32,64)
- different Loss-Function (L1Loss, L2Loss, SmoothL1Loss)
- additional Data Augmentation (RandomPerspective, RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.2))
- different CNNs (AlexNet, ResNet101)
- different Outputdimensions of the cutted CNN (1,5,10,25,75,100,250,500)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi AdrianD. I suggest you ask your Primary Question right up front. I think your Primary Question is, "How can I improve the separation of the classes? "

Comment: Hello Joe Codeswell,

you're right.
My question is: "How can I improve the separation of the 5 classes?".